# How to avoid git from showing merge messages on editor?

Tags: git

From some days now, not sure why, each time I do a git pull on my local machine, to pull remote repo changes, I get a merge message opened on my editor.

This is, indeed and without doubt, annoying.

Does anyone had this thing before, if so, what did you do?

On my local git configuration I tried:

```
git config --global care.mergeoptions --no-edit
```

No avail.

Maybe because it's a not a `mergeoption` but a `pull` (followed by a merge). ?

Please advice

Comment: Have you changed merge to be by default `no-ff`?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean **core**.mergeoptions? That said, AFAIK mergeoptions only apply to a specific branch, you'd use `branch.<name>.mergeoptions`.

Comment: @meagar so I'm working on `dev` branch, you mean I should `git config --global branch.dev.mergeoptions --no-edit` - I've tested. Apparently is working but I'm still not sure if it will kept it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting those messages because you have locally commited changes that are not in the upstream repo being pulled.  Quite literally, you are working on a different branch and you have to merge the changes in.  If you don't want to have an explicit merge commit, you can do a `git rebase` on your local tree after the merge, which will eliminate the merge commit.  This will still require that you close your editor to create a default merge message.  You can further optimize this by doing `git pull --rebase`, which does the rebase automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I have two questions. You seem to talk about "Changes not being pulled by the upstream repo ?" 1) What is a upstream repo ? Is this the remote bare repo reference? 2)Pulled were? Sorry for those newbie questions.